# In Exchange 2010, how do I tell which alias was e-mail sent to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2010

I have multiple aliases in my Exchange account. But when I look to the TO field in Outlook, it displays the main account e-mail address instead of the alias the mail was sent to.

How do I tell which alias it was sent to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Internet header, that will display the email address it was sent to. In Outlook 2013, go to File, Properties and look at Internet Header.

Comment: Is that the only way? I was hoping there was a more user friendly way...